# Have refreshed state in Hook in loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, setstate

Replacing the phrase - based on start and end index - by visibleText.

The problem - there is multiple phrases(each phrase changing per iteration)
.
So the value of transformedText is not refreshing by setTransformedText hook.

How to have changed transformedText - after setTransformedText - in each iteration?

```
for(const i in phrasesByCategory){

  const startIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].start_char;
  const endIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].end_char;
  const hiddenText = transformedText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  const visibleText = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex)

  const replacedPhrase  = replaceAt(transformedText, hiddenText, visibleText, startIndex, endIndex)

  setTransformedText(replacedPhrase)
}
```

---

The hook is string:

```
  const [transformedText, setTransformedText] = useState("")
```

---

It's replace the first iteration:

```
  const makeVisible = (phrasesByCategory) => {

    let currentText = transformedText
    setTransformedText((transformedText)=> {
      for(const i in phrasesByCategory){
        const startIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].start_char;
        const endIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].end_char;
        const hiddenText = transformedText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        const visibleText = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        const replacedPhrase  = replaceAt(transformedText, hiddenText, visibleText, startIndex, endIndex)
        currentText = replacedPhrase
      }
      return currentText;
  })
}
```

---

Edit current solution - which finally anonymyse and unanomyse that phrases:

```
  const anonymyseByCategory = (phrasesByCategory, visible) => {
    const textArray = [transformedText];
    for (const i in phrasesByCategory) {
      const startIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].start_char;
      const endIndex = phrasesByCategory[i].end_char;
      let hiddenText = visible
        ? textArray[i].substring(startIndex, endIndex)
        : textArray[i].substring(startIndex, endIndex).replace(textArray[i].substring(startIndex, endIndex), 'X'.repeat(textArray[i].substring(startIndex, endIndex).length))
      const visibleText = text.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
      const sentenceWithReplacedPhrases = visible
        ? replaceAt(textArray[i], hiddenText, visibleText, startIndex, endIndex)
        : replaceAt(textArray[i], visibleText, hiddenText, startIndex, endIndex)
      textArray.push(sentenceWithReplacedPhrases)
      setTransformedText(sentenceWithReplacedPhrases);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is your state property an array ? Please post your `useState` line.

Comment: sure - it just string. - the logic with replacing working - but in 2 iterations - the second one replace the first changed phrase - so only the last iteration have replaced string.

Comment: transformedText is sentence -> and each iteration changing one word in that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have something like:

```
let [transformedText, setTransformedText] = useState('Hello World');
```

Since you are using the previous value of a state property (`transformedText`) in order to update it, you have to call your state property setter (`setTransformedText`) with a callback.

```
setTransformedText((transformedText)=> {
    var hiddenText = ...;
    var visibleText = ...;
    var replacedPhrase = replaceAt(...);
    return replacedPhrase;
});
```

This is due to the fact that, state updates [may be asynchronous in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: Thanks, it probably will work - but handle only one word - what if there is 5 word in sentence to change?

Comment: You can call `setTransformedText` inside your for loop.
Or, you can put your for loop inside the `setTransformedText`, use an accumulator variable (`currentText`) and return it, after the end of the for loop.

Comment: if i using for in setHook - then it change first iteration (edited question)

Comment: Ok. Declare `let currentText = transformedText` before the for loop. Instead of returning `replacedText`, set `currentText = replacedPhrase`. After the for loop return `currentText`.

Comment: that solution dont work ;/

Comment: Please show the updated code.

Comment: done - i already edited

Comment: Ok - i resolved